# global sections of ideal sheaf quotient $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I^{2}}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X=\mathbb{P}_{k}^{2}$, $P$ a point in $X$ with its ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$. Then I would like to know what is $H^{0}(X, \mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^{2})$.

My first thought was to consider the exact sequence
$$0\to \mathcal{I}^{2}\to \mathcal{I}\to \mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^{2}\to 0.$$
Taking the long exact sequence,
$$0\to H^{0}(X,\mathcal{I}^{2}) \to H^{0}(X,\mathcal{I})\to H^{0}(X,\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^{2}) \to H^{1}(X,\mathcal{I}^{2})\to \cdots.$$
The first two $H^{0}$ are zero since they're powers of the ideal sheaf, then makes the fourth arrow an injective map. Hence what I only know is that dimension is bounded up by $h^{1}(X,\mathcal{I}^{2})$. Then what should I do next?

Comment: Since $\mathcal I$ is a maximal ideal, $\mathcal I/\mathcal I^2$ is the Zariski cotangent space to $X$ at $P$ (the sheaf is supported at $P$ so this is not surprising), so if we blur the distinction between the cotangent space and the cotangent sheaf then $\mathcal I/\mathcal I^2$ "is its own space of global sections" in the obvious sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tabes Bridges' comment pretty much answers the question but I want to elaborate on some of the facts. Let's first consider the affine situation. Take an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and pick your closed point $\operatorname{Spec} k \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ corresponding to a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Associated to such a point is a quasicoherent sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ of ideals, which is just the quasicoherent sheaf corresponding to $\mathfrak{m}$.

Now the quotient $\mathcal{I} / \mathcal{I}^2$ of a quasicoherent sheaf of ideals is often called the **conormal sheaf** because, geometrically, it identifies with the dual of the normal bundle of the closed subscheme. As the closed subscheme is just a point, this is geometrically the same as the cotangent space at that point, and indeed $\mathcal{I} / \mathcal{I}^2$ is also the **cotangent sheaf** at the closed point $[\mathfrak{m}]$.

When we say 'at the closed point' what do we mean? I claim that $\mathcal{I} / \mathcal{I}^2$ is the skyscraper sheaf supported on the closed point $[\mathfrak{m}]$ with value $\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2$. I don't actually know what the best way of seeing this (and I'd be happy if someone can remark on this), though the following commutative algebra lemma suffices in many cases:

**Lemma.** Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module, and let $I$ be an ideal of $A$. Then $\operatorname{Supp}(M / IM) = V(I) \cap \operatorname{Supp} M$.

Now, turning to the global situation, nothing really changes. All the behaviour of the cotangent bundle should be 'local', i.e. concentrated around a small open neighbourhood of whatever closed point you consider. Therefore, it remains the case when $X$ is not affine that $\mathcal{I} / \mathcal{I}^2$ will be a skyscraper sheaf. In particular, the global sections may be identified with $\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2$ after choosing an open neighbourhood $\operatorname{Spec} A$ of $P$ such that $P$ identifies with $[\mathfrak{m}]$.

**Remark:** The module $\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2$ in fact has the structure of a vector space over the field $k = A / \mathfrak{m}$. Let's consider the example $X = \mathbb{P}^2_k$ that you're interested in, and assume that $k$ is algebraically closed*. Locally, this variety looks like $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]$, and a closed point corresponds to a maximal ideal $(x - a,y - b)$. A direct computation shows that $\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2$ must then be $2$-dimensional as a $k$-vector space. This is in line with the geometric interpretation: $\mathbb{P}^2$, as say a manifold, is $2$-dimensional after all.

*: Without this assumption there are additional maximal ideals, and the observation needs to be corrected. Thanks to Georges Elencwajg for noting this.

Comment: $\mathscr{m}$ is generated by $(x_{0}-a,x_{1}-b,x_{2}-c)$, and $\mathscr{m}^{2}$ is generated by degree $2$ product of above generators. So I think it should be all linear combinations of those generators, whose dimension is 3?

Comment: A standard affine open subset of $\mathbb{P}^2$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]$. A maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ is then of the form $(x - a, y - b)$, and $\mathfrak{m} / \mathfrak{m}^2$ should therefore be $2$-dimensional. Geometrically, this is the answer you would want --- $\mathbb{P}^2$ is a smooth $2$-dimensional variety after all!

Comment: Thanks! Is there a similar theory for $\mathcal{I}^{2}/\mathcal{I}^{3}$? Or more general, $\mathcal{I}^{n}/\mathcal{I}^{n+1}$?

Comment: Hmm! I suppose that a related quotient $\mathcal{I} / \mathcal{I}^3$ would capture not just the (first-order) tangent structure, but also have some kind of second-order information... But I've never seen it studied!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I was mostly focussed on correcting the OP's attempt in which a maximal ideal $(x-a,y-b,z-c)$ was considered, but you're right, I was being sloppy. i've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Dear Jeroen: yes, your answer is excellent and I was just nitpicking for the sake of those who want to learn scheme theory in all generality. Anyway, a well deserved  +1 [Bent U Belg? Nederlands?]

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Ik ben Nederlands. :) You can tell us apart by the convention that Belgians capitalise their 'van's and 'der's while Dutch people don't.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen: I didn't know this interesting and subtle particularity. And indeed my thesis co-advisor was the late Van **de** Ven. Another charming Dutch-Flemish idiosyncrasy is to start a family name with an apostrophe standing for "het", as in  't Hooft (Dutch Nobel physicist), 't Serstevens (Belgian writer).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes. :) It's one of my go-to nerdy facts that I often share. Curiously, then, when you have a name with just a single 'tussenvoegsel' (e.g. 'De Vries') you can only tell the Dutch apart from the Belgian if the first name is in front of it.